# Redshift - Passing columns as a list

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a set of columns passed into a python list. I am trying to see if I can pass this list as part of the select statement in redshift.

```
list_name = ['col_a', 'col_b']
```

Trying to pass this list into the below query:

```
cur.execute("""select {} from table""".format(list_name))
```

I get the below message:

```
ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'col_a'"
```

The above SQL should be equivalent to

```
select col_a, col_b from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a list into a string by using `join()`, specifying the text to put between entries. For example this:

```py
','.join(['col_a', 'col_b'])
```

would return:

```
'col_a,col_b'
```

Therefore, you can use it when creating the SQL query:

```
cur.execute("select {} from table".format(','.join(list_name)))
```

Or using an f-string:

```py
cur.execute(f"select {','.join(list_name)} from table")
```